# Postgres : Unable to extract data from a bytea column which stores json array data

Tags: postgresql, bytea

I'm trying to extract data from a bytea column which stores JSON data in Postgres 11.9 version.

However, the my code is throwing an error:

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ...

Here is the sample data:

```
create table EMPLOYEE (PAYMENT bytea,NAME character varying);
insert into EMPLOYEE
  values ('[{"totalCode":{"code":"EMPLOYER_TAXES"},"totalValue":{"amount":122.5,"currencyCode":"USD"}},{"totalCode":{"code":"OTHER_PAYMENTS"},"totalValue":{"amount":0.0,"currencyCode":"USD"}},{"totalCode":{"code":"GROSS_PAY"},"totalValue":{"amount":1000.0,"currencyCode":"USD"}},{"totalCode":{"code":"TOTAL_HOURS"},"totalValue":{"amount":40.0}}]'::bytea,'Tom')
;
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT *    
 FROM EMPLOYEE left outer join lateral    
  jsonb_array_elements(PAYMENT::text::jsonb) element1 on true  ;
```

Please help me in accessing data from this array. Data is always JSON in format.
There was a restriction to use bytea for this column.

Comment: Don't store a JSON as binary data (`bytea`). That's even worse than storing it as string. Use the proper data type!

Comment: The real question is: why are you storing JSON in a `bytea` column and not in a `jsonb` column. What is the reasoning for that "restriction". It makes no sense whatsoever (at least to me). You should let that person who decided this, solve your problem. They should feel the consequences of their decisions.

Comment: For our application we use two data bases, Oracle for some clients data and Postgres for others. The Application Java code is the same. The Oracle columns were suggested to be BLOB for storing JSON data quoting the below reference: https://blogs.oracle.com/jsondb/storing-json-in-blob-columns. Now, if we use json data type in Postgres, the Java code is throwing errors: nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot cast type bytea to jsonb.